# Seemingly simple mysql query, proving to be tough

Tags: mysql

I have a very basic mysql table called memberships, that tracks which people belong to which groups.  People can belong to many groups.

It contains 3 fields:  id, person_id, group_id

I need to select all the person_ids that have group_ids of '20' and '53'.  The people must belong to ONLY those 2 groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.person_id
FROM memberships a
JOIN memberships b
    ON a.person_id = b.person_id 
    AND b.group_id = 53
LEFT JOIN memberships c
    ON a.person_id = c.person_id 
    AND c.group_id NOT IN (20,53)
WHERE a.group_id  = 20 AND c.person_id IS NULL;
```

Although you could also go for a [`NOT EXISTS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) format.